# Remove extra space around GridView programmatically

Tags: android, gridview

I am trying to make a `GridView` programmatically in my java class and it all works fine. The problem is the auto-generated 5 pixel padding around the `GridView`. In the xml I manage to remove it using:

```
android:listSelector="@null"
```

But I do not manage to do anything similar in java. I have tried some workarounds like making the `GridView` 10 pixels larger then the actual screen with no luck.

Does anyone have any code for this?

Edit:

The answer by me does not solve the problem. There is still a bounty going. 
Here is my `GridView` code:

```
    GridView gridView = new GridView(this);
    gridView.setNumColumns(someInt);
    gridView.setAdapter (new MyCustomAdapter(this));
    gridView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
            customValue,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
    );
```

Answer (score 6):

- One way to ensure the padding appears same on screens with different density is by converting it to DIP units.

  ```
  int padding = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, -5, 
                                      getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
  ```
- Other thing you can try is to define a null drawable in xml..

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
      <drawable name="null_drawable">@null</drawable>
      ...
  </resources>
  ```

  Then call `setSelector(R.drawable.null_drawable);`

***Update:***

- Define your `GridView` in its own xml and inflate it.

  *layout/mygrid.xml*

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <GridView 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:listSelector="@null"/>
  ```

  In java,

  ```
  GridView gridView = (GridView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.mygrid, null);
  gridView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(customValue, 
                          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
  gridView.setNumColumns(someInt);
  gridView.setAdapter (new MyCustomAdapter(this));
  ```

Comment: Gets error in file on the java code, and no change on the xml.

Comment: You mean it crashed? or was a syntax error? wt was the error?

Comment: I have thought about that solotion, but I want to check if there were any ways of doing this 100% programmatically, without using xml since importing multiple xml into a class often is unstabel(my own experiences)

Comment: what problems did you face inflating? what do you mean "importing multiple xml into a class"?

Comment: I am saying that this question is about doing this programattically, and if that fails I use you solotion.

Comment: But I dont think there is any difference now between inflating and creating in java, as the view you will inflate is one single view(not a deep heirarchy of views, such that it makes inflating costly).. So you can go ahead with this option without any downsides.

Comment: I give this question an upvote, but I do not accept it due to that it does not answear my question completely. In other words good answear but not to solve it 100% programatically. Because of your upvotes you also get about 50 of the bounty too. It looks like I have to use this solution anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it sort of by:

```
    gridView.setPadding(-5, 0, -5, 0);
```

But you need different padding for different screens. But it is not a complete solution. Functional modifications of this code will be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

To get the same effect like using `android:listSelector="@null"`, but in code you need to use [setSelector()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setSelector%28int%29) as marvinXXII mentioned.
But you need to pass in a valid ResourceId or use the `setSelector(Drawable sel)` variant.
Unfortunatly its not possible to pass `null` into that method as that will lead to a NullPointerException.
The workaround which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234292/creating-an-empty-drawable-in-android) is to use this:

```
gridView.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: Better but it is still pixels in the side of the GridView.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use setPadding to remove that problem while creating dynamic gridview.

```
int grids_height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, (int) (Row_num * 80),
            getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Log.v("", "" + grids_height);
    gridview = new GridView(this);
    gridview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            grids_height));
    gridview.setPadding(0, 3, 0, 0);
    gridview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    gridview.setNumColumns(7);
    gridview.setVerticalSpacing(1);
    gridview.setHorizontalSpacing(1);
    gridview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    gridview.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
```

Comment: No good. I have experimented with setPadding quite a lot, and I have to set different padding for different screens to fit. And android devices has quite a lot of different screensizes.

Answer (score 0):

[setSelector(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setSelector%28int%29) (from `AbsListView`) isn't it what you are looking for?

Like `setSelector(0)`

Comment: No good. Causes crash, or error in file. Wants me to corect it to setSelected.

Comment: It shouldn't be so, can you show your code with GridView initialization?

Comment: If it really crashes, that stack trace is needed to understand why it crashes

Comment: it crashed because 0 is not a valid resource id

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this question [Why are there extra pixels around my Android GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036990/why-are-there-extra-pixels-around-my-android-gridview)? In that case the problem was that the image being used as a selector on the gridview had a padding.

Applying the suggested solution from that question programmatically you would [set the selector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setSelector%28int%29)

```
gridView.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following settings works for me:

```
public ContactContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    gallery = new GridView(context, attrs);
    gallery.setNumColumns(numColumns);
    gallery.setStretchMode(stretchMode);
    gallery.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(smoothScrollbar);
    gallery.setSelector(listSelector);
    gallery.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    this.addView(gallery);
}
```

I use it in combination with this piece of xml code:

```
<de.ramicro.SClip.components.ContactContainer
    android:id="@+id/gridview_gallery_contacts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/contact_gallery_bottom_bar"
    android:layout_below="@id/contact_gallery_top_bar"
    android:padding="0dip"/>
```

I think that what you need is maybe the combination of a transparent Selector and gravity set to CENTER_HORIZONTAL.

Comment: Can you please upload your your stretchMode, smoothScrollbar and listSelector?

Comment: private int listSelector = android.R.color.transparent;
private int numColumns = 2;
private boolean smoothScrollbar = true;
private int stretchMode = GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH;